# mvc4 forms auth adds "guid" token to querystring when deployed to iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have an MVC4 application that is set up for forms authentication and uses the SimpleMembershipProvider.

I have marked all controllers except Account with the [Authorize] attribute.

When I deploy the site to an IIS server, the urls have a "GUID"-like querystring added to them (this doesn't happen on my development machine.

For example:

```
(dev machine) -   http://mysite/Home/Edit
(iis)             http://mysite/(X(6QK3qJe4dH34ynvHrs3PKduE5dlpsx-8wi5Kno4EXthY8WFPkbYWgNKENdNLbuo2jxazSYYAExxsouPyvfUK22gnZyQ11S-g4eMvPxA5AOoxHcLbSjTciN3VEp56LLYi1WYGKCJ54SVUHADF5J4wa7d3vaf6Y7xTAfOhmryN4iI6_7FC-ppruA9UjADwYwnnPs0))/Home/Edit
```

This also seems to have the effect that the first time I navigate to another page with an ActionLink, it makes me login again (I assume this is because the guid (I guess this is some authentication token?) is not generated by Html.ActionLink)

How can I get rid of this?

In  IIS the authentication settings are

Anonymous Authentication: Enabled

ASP.NET Impersonation: Disabled

Basic Auth: Disabled - HTTP 401 CHallenge

Digest Auth: Disabled - HTTP 401 CHallenge

Forms Auth: Enabled- HTTP 302 Login/Redirect

Windows Auth: Disabled - HTTP 401 CHallenge

In my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Security/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using cookie-less FormsAuthentication. What if you specify the `cookieless` attribute with `UseCookies` on the `form` tag:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Security/Login" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: There was an .NET bug which caused cookieless auth to happen when the client was iOS Chrome - it may be related:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx